# root folder redirection issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm using wamp server for laravel.
my url is  localhost/pjct_name/public.
I have the url in ajax as given below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url : "../getCustomer",
        ...  
       });
```

Its working for edit but not request

```
Route::get('/request', [ 
        'middleware' => 'roles',
        'roles' => [ 
                'Requestor' 
        ],   
        function(){return View('layouts.request');}
]);
/*Edit request*/
Route::get('/edit/{id}',array('as'=>'edit','middleware' => 'checksession',
        function($id){
        $data['id'] =$id;
        return View::make('layouts.request',$data);
    })
);
```

in request page redirect to http://localhost/asset/getCustomer
but I need to redirect as http://localhost/asset/public/getCustomer
how to write htaccess for redirection.
I have tried as

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^$ /public [L]
```

but no luck

Comment: Use absolute URLs instead of relative URLs.

Comment: Setting up a virtualhost would be a way easier way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Change url in AJAX request according to Route

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url : "/request",
        ...  
       });
```

Also change the method from 'get' to 'post' for Route in web.php

```
Route::post('/request', [ 
        'middleware' => 'roles',
        'roles' => [ 
                'Requestor' 
        ],   
        function(){return View('layouts.request');}
]);
```

Redirect your page after successful AJAX request.

```
success: function (response) {
    windoe.location.href = "/your-next-page";
},
```

Hope its work for you,